# Can a VM span multiple nodes with Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, cloud-computing, cloud

With Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud (UEC, or Ubuntu's private cloud offering), can a VM span multiple nodes or only one node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean can one VM actually execute across multiple physical machines? if that's what you mean then no, no it can't. If that's not what you mean could you clarify please.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. That's what I needed to know. I also found this from more than one source, so I believe you have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [ScaleMP](http://www.scalemp.com) does this